# How to fast copy files with Mobile Center(Active Sync) to windows mobile devices

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, file-copying

There is a file that should be copied into windows mobile device. The file size is about 40 MB and here is my code:

```
OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPI clsPDTDevice = new RAPI();

string DeviceDbPath = "\\FlashFX Disk\\Table\\db_assetSL.db";
string BackOfficeDbPath = string.Format(@"{0}\Table\db_assetSL.db", Application.StartupPath);

clsPDTDevice.Connect();
clsPDTDevice.CopyFileToDevice(BackOfficeDbPath, DeviceDbPath, true);
```

These codes are working but my problem is the time. Over than 40 seconds for less than 40 MB is not suitable at all. I have copied the file with windows explorer and the result was same.

Is there anything wrong with my codes?
If this is mobile center problem, can anyone show me another way to copy the file?

`db_assetSL.db` is a SQLite database if it helps .

I could be more hopeful if I could copy this file without mobile center. Is there any way to compress this db and after copying unzip that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fast copy such big file but I could decrease file size by using `Vacuum;` command with sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

Copying files via USB and to a Flash is mostly slow. As you said, even File Explorer is not faster.
For USB: do not use a hub but connect the device directly to the PC.

If you have the choice, switch the "USB to PC" to not use "Enhanced Network..." support on the device, I feel that the 'old' PPP_Peer is faster.

Pending on the device it may be possible to copy the file via a network connection. Some device come with a ftp server. You may install a ftp server on the device or even write your own socket file transfer code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to copy my file to this drive because active sync makes a drive with letter "\" and a big confusion occur when I am giving destination address to File.Copy(source,destination). I should use Rapi.CopyFileToDevice that is very slow and I don't want it.

Comment: If you are using WMDC and opennetcf there is no other option. You may switch to a network protocol.